# Unable to create an instance of "ActivityManager" using Powershell?

Tags: user-profile

Would like to work with the "ActivityManager" object however it is throwing an error:

$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteurl)
$context = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($site)
$upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$profile = $upm.GetUserProfile([string]$loginname)
$am = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityManager($profile, $context)

**Error:**
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "ActivityManager" and the argument count: "2".

any help?

Ok,it helps

$siteurl = "http://siteurl/";
$loginname = "domain/user";
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteurl);
$context = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($site);
$ServerContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site;
$upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context);
$profile = $upm.GetUserProfile([string]$loginname);
$am = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityManager($profile, $ServerContext);

any help how can I deselect the "Manager change" newsfeed settings?

Comment: i would ask you to add this question that you have added to a new one, as it is now a different topic. makes finding stuff in the archive easier

Comment: @karthikeyan please split up the questions into two seperate questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes two arguments:

```
public ActivityManager(
    UserProfile userProfile,
    SPServiceContext serviceContext
)
```

You are giving it a `Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext`, not a `SPServiceContext`.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee585780.aspx)

Comment: also use Get-SPSite instead of instantiating a site object like that

Answer (score 1):

To deselect a News feed setting, you would have to get the `ActivityType` from the `ActivityTypes` collection of `ActivityManager` class. And then use the `IsSet` property of the [ActivityPreferencePerType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.activityfeed.activitypreferencepertype_members.aspx) to set the news feed to false.

But bear in mind that Microsoft disallows these settings from being changed by anyone except for the user who owns the account. In your case, running the code via console command while logged in as the farm administrator is not equal to the user's account for which the settings apply.

You can make a work around by somehow having the user run this code

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, could you share a reference?